# Why is Visual C++ 6.0 no longer available on MSDN?

Tags: msdn, legacy, visual-c++-6

I was trying to do some legacy work, and looked up Visual C++ 6 on MSDN. I can no longer see it, and the best I can do is Visual C++ 4.2!

Does anyone know why this is the case? Is there a way to get it still from MSDN?

Comment: Why? Just upgrade to VS2013 - what use of such an old tool?

Comment: umm.. when you are using a codebase that is many years old? Typically you would want to compile the code in the closest working environment before remediating to a newer one such as VS2013.

Comment: It is possible that it will compile in VS 2013 right off the bat, however when not then I want to recreate the original compilation environment as closely as possible.

Comment: There is VC++ 4.2 on MSDN? Where?

Comment: @Dialecticus It is there in my 'Premium' subscription. Just navigate products starting with 'V'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That was the result of a lawsuit, started by Sun Microsystems, the owners of Java.  Microsoft obtained a license to implement Java on Windows and implemented their own JVM.  Giving it capabilities beyond the JVM implementation that Sun maintained.  Sun was not happy about it and sued.  It was settled out of court, Microsoft agreed to discontinue their JVM and all of the products that used it.  Like VC++ 5.0 and 6.0, Windows 98 and ME, Office 2000 and XP, IE 5.5.  Only VB6 survived since its IDE didn't use the JVM.

You can still obtain a license at an auction site like Ebay.  Caveat emptor, prices are high.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I do recall that event, although I thought Visual C++ 6 (and 5) did not have any of the offending JVM inside them? There was a product called Visual J++ that was affected.

Comment: @user2043 Maybe in MSDN VC6 is distributed in a Visual Studio set.